# Download a thumbnail instead of whole image

Tags: java, android, image, url, download

I have an application that shows the front page of some magazines. Those images are in high resolution. It's useless and battery/time/data consuming to download the whole image if I'm only going to show low resolution picture. So the question is: How can I get a thumbnail URL from the image URL so I don't need to download the image?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you may want to check out [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/). You can send them your images for storage and then easily get dynamically generated thumbnails by requesting special URLs.

Comment: This really seems to be what I needed. I'm sorry if I wasn't so accurate with the question. It would be perfect if I can just refference an URL instead of having to upload it.

Comment: Unfortunately you still have to upload your image to their service, but once you do, it does save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a server-side process (PHP, ASP...etc) to create the thumbnails, then just download from the new URL.

Comment: I made some research on this before posting, and it seems like every online thumbnail provider looks like this one [link]www.makeathumbnail.com[/link]. They let you upload an image and get your thumbnail but no possibility to code this.

On the other hand there are hundreds of Web-snapshot sites that provide thumbnails from a webpage snapshot. I'm asking for something simpler, it has to be out there.

Thanks. Now i know it may already exist.

Comment: You can find some very simple PHP image-resizing/caching scripts (phpThumb for one) and implement it without need for a third party site / software.

Answer (score 3):

I think Dave is right, the optimal solution is to modify the image server side.  However, it also sounds like you may not be 100% in control of the images coming down to you.  That doesn't leave you with a lot of options in terms of pulling down less data...

What you can do to minimize the memory usage on the device is to down-sample the image to the appropriate size so that the image you save in memory and show is just as big as it needs to be.

You can do that with code that looks like this (remember to clean up your streams):

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        final BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        final Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE:
        opt.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opt);
```

You can read here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html to learn how to get the appropriate sample size and using **inJustDecodeBounds**.

Be patient... Arithmetic is hard.

Comment: After getting the image I feed it to a ImageView as a Drawable. I thought the ImageView would take care of this for my. what's the point of holding a Drawable with bigger resolution than you can show? 
I will implement this if I fail with the thumbnail thing. Tahnks!

Comment: So the ImageView will scale the image down to its bounds by default, but it'll keep the whole image in memory, so if the bounds of the ImageView get bigger the image will stretch/shrink.  It's on the developer to sample down the image to fit our needs.  Sigh, work.

Comment: Thanks again. It seems like this feature is what pinch zoom uses. Implemented.
Now low RAM devices will love me :)

Answer (score 0):

If an image was made interlaced/for progressive download, you could conceivably just download some of the file data and use that to create a thumbnail, but that's a pretty specialized use case that isn't likely to be widely supported.

Otherwise, given *deep* knowledge of the image format *and* servers that support retrieving specific byte ranges you could selectively download only the necessary image data to create a thumbnail, but that would be *extremely* difficult.

In all likelihood, **while your idea is interesting and potentially useful, there's just no way to do it**.

Depending on the number of magazines, you might consider having a separate server that downloads the cover images and prepares thumbnails of them.  Then your mobile app could query that server first, and if a thumbnail was available use it instead of downloading the full-size image.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I was thinking about an online service. I give them the image URL and they give me the thumbnail URL.